# Postfix : change email from unix_user@domain to a something@domain

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have two domains on a server, they are rarely used and they have 2 ubuntu users like

```
domain1_user
domain2_user
```

and I want to associate email addresses like

```
info@domain1
info@domain2
```

Obviously I can't create unix accounts as they would be having same names so I need to alias somehow each user to each email address. Currently my emails are sent out as

```
domain1_user@domain1
```

instead of

```
info@domain1
```

In my efforts and after some research I modified already the /etc/postfix/virtual file to have something like

```
info@domain1 domain1_user
```

I also modified the /etc/aliases similarly with

```
info@domain1: domain1_user
```

still when I send emails the same "domain1_user@domain1" comes up as the sender instead of the desired "info@domain1"

NOTE: I'm currently sending emails out from server using Webmin / Postfix / User Mailboxes, if this makes any difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix doesn't set the `From:` header. That header is set by whomever *creates* the e-mail. You have to configure the `From:` in whatever application sends your e-mail.

Comment: ....but the From header must match the envelope From for good deliverability. How the evnelope head is (initially) set depends on how the email is submitted to the MTA.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment elsewhere, you need to ensure that the both the "From" header and the envelope From contain the desired value.

The process recomended by the Postfix people is to use [smtp_generic_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps). You just add a lookup table and reference it from main.cf whether this applies to your usage scenario and your method of sending email (SMTP submission behaves differently from file + sendmail -t -i) will need testing.